# My foreach loop is not working as the previous I've done

Tags: html, laravel, foreach, laravel-6

I'm new ton Laravel (also to StackOverflow), and I'm trying to show data in my home.blade.php table from PhpMyAdmin using a foreach loop. However, it's not working correctly, and I can't figure out where the problem is. I have other tables working with foreach, and I've followed the same steps with this table.

**User Model**

```php
protected $table = 'users';

protected $fillable = ['id','name','edad','direccion_personal','celular','foto','email','direccion_sucursal_id'];
```

**UserController**

```php
public function index()
{
    $Usuarios = User::all();
    $array = ['usuarios' => $Usuarios];

    return view('home')->with($array);
}
```

Finally, here's my tbody:

```php
<tbody>
@foreach ($usuarios as $Usuarios)
    <div>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" style="text-align:center;">{{ $Usuarios->id }}</th>
            <td style="text-align:center;">{{ $Usuarios->nombre }}</td>
            .
            .
            .
        </tr>
    </div>
</tbody>
@endforeach
```

Comment: `but It's not working correctly and I can't find where's the problem.` so whats the problem? XD any errors? and remember `div` are not meant to be inside `tbody`, only `tr` which then contains `td`. see [w3schools for table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to erase `div` tags. According to Laravel's error page: "Undefined variable: "Usuarios". I've already renamed it according to User Model and UserController@index but anyway it doesn't show the data.

Comment: is it in the compiled blade or in the controller? if its in the compiled blade, you can fire `php artisan view:clear` if my memory serves me right. or simply remove view folder inside `storage/app`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the array?

```
    public function index(){
        $usuarios = User::all();
        return view('home', compact('usuarios'));
    }
```

Then:

```
<tbody>

@foreach ($usuarios as $us)
 <div>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row" style="text-align:center;">{{$us->id}}</th>
    <td style="text-align:center;">{{$us->nombre}}</td>
       .
       .
       .
  </tr>
 </div>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: You're right! It worked perfectly!. In addition, I have to say that I had created a UserControler to perform that, however, I had to work with HomeController then I followed your instructions and it worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're having troubles with the foreach loop. is not working correctly... but, I'm not sure what kind of problem is... if my answer does not work for you, please update your question so you can get more help

I see you close your  inside the foreach loop.
That way you will end with lots of  closing tags with just one opening...

Try moving that close tag outside the loop

```html
<tbody>
@foreach ($usuarios as $Usuarios)
 <div>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row" style="text-align:center;">{{$Usuarios->id}}</th>
    <td style="text-align:center;">{{$Usuarios->nombre}}</td>
       .
       .
       .
  </tr>
 </div>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach closes outside the `</tbody>` tag, and opens inside it. Your table body is thus closed after the first iteration of the loop, and never opened again, so with each iteration you now have an additional `</tbody>` line. This is invalid markup, and will break your site's output.